# Spring Integration - Service Activator - Method Signature

Tags: spring-integration

I have a general question. We are upgrading some old code to v4.1.3 of `spring-integration`. Let's say we have a service activator that receives a domain object of type Foo, and returns the same object on the output channel (after changing some properties of that object).

Our existing code has signatures like below. Is it the right convention? If I don't need the headers, can I return my payload directly and will the framework wrap it into a Message?:

```
public Message<Foo> computeValue(Foo payload, @Headers Map<String, Object> headerMap) { 
   //... 
   return MessageBuilder.withPayload(payload).copyHeaders(headerMap).build();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you don't need do that. More over that is pointless because in case of Service Activator the Framework populates request headers to the reply message independently of your effort.

So, consider do not care about headers at all if you don't need to do some specific logic on the matter.

Comment: Ok Thanks again Artem, as always! To re-iterate what you said for my understanding: just by doing a "return payload;" the framework still will retain all headers and convert the payload into a message.

Comment: Not convert, but wrap. Makes your object as a `payload` of a reply message